# Comunicate between different opened documents

Tags: excel, vba

It is possible to comunicate between to sheets on separated excel files opened on same machine?

I need to write a cell on another excel file.
I cant find any way to do it, i need a tip to help.

Comment: Are you sure you have different Excel instances? Or do you just have 2 files open in the same Excel instance? Can you please include in your question ([edit]) how these 2 files are opened (manually or by code, if by code please post the relevant code part). • If it is the same Excel instance with 2 files you can easily access them by `Workbooks("OtherBook.xlsm").Worksheets("DesiredSheet")`.

Comment: With document opened is very dificult, i will change requirements and the document must be closed.thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Dim wb1 as Workbook    
Set wb1 = Workbooks("Book1.xlsx")

Dim wb2 as Workbook
Set wb2 = Workbooks("Book2.xlsx")
```

And then use constructions like this, for example:

```
wb2.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") = wb1.Worksheets("SomeSheet").Range("C12")
```